# Xml transformation with variable passing in php

Tags: php, xml, xslt

My input xml file:

```
 <root>
 <child/> 
</root>
```

My expected output would be in view page source:

```
<root>
  <child> 
    <new_element>new1</new_element>
    <new_element>new2</new_element> 
    <new_element>new3</new_element>
  </child>
</root>
```

Actual output i am getting in view page source:

```
<root>
  <child>&lt;new_element&gt;new1&lt;/new_element&gt;   &lt;new_element&gt;new2&lt;/new_element&gt;   &lt;new_element&gt;new3&lt;/new_element&gt;</child>
</root>
```

My xlst code is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="test"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/child">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My php code is :

```
<?php
            $xslt = new xsltProcessor;
            $xslt->importStyleSheet(DomDocument::load('test.xsl'));

            $val = '<new_element>new1</new_element>   <new_element>new2</new_element>   <new_element>new3</new_element>';
            $xslt->setParameter('','test',$val);
            echo $view = $xslt->transformToXML(DomDocument::load('test.xml'));
?>
```

By running this in browser i am getting the output with out parsing xml tags. Please find out where i am went wrong.

Comment: Remove space between <new_element> tags. Then retry.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter $test is typed as a string, **NOT** a document, so your style-sheet is behaving exactly as you have asked it to behave. I don't believe that there is any standard XSLT function to parse a text string into an XDM document.

To achieve your aim, you should pass a filename as your parameter value, not the string content of text.xsl. Then inside your stylesheet, you can use the document() function.

Comment: In my case i would like to avoid writing the xml files and use xml data dynamically. Please suggest me if there is any possibility

Comment: If you want a generic solution for all XML, then No, this is not possible. If you are in a position to make some constraints on the shape of your data, then, Maybe, depending on your constraints.